# Loading content from database for listview on click of the button?

Tags: android, listview, button

I created an application based on quiz.For that i used listview to populate the questions from the database but it populates all the question at a time.can u help me how to get one question on a button click?`MainActivity` contains the code in `onCreate`

```
   l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
   myAdap adap1=new myAdap(this,c1);
   c1=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM donut",null);
   l1.setAdapter(adap1);
```

Myadapter class contains 4 TextViews.

Comment: l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        c1=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM donut",null);
        myAdap adap1=new myAdap(this,c1);
        l1.setAdapter(adap1);

Comment: pasted my code again?

Comment: l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
c1=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM donut",null); check size of data
myAdap adap1=new myAdap(this,c1); than create adapeer
l1.setAdapter(adap1);

Comment: First thing you have to switch your second line with third line. Then your passing c1 which is a cursor to adapter. So are you fetching data from cursor in adapter???

Comment: Yes Clairvoyant.I fetched data from db using cursor and then storing it to the adapter to display in listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i try to retrieve contents from DB to ListView it displays all the rows at once but i want to retrieve one by one.So i used the below query to do that.
Finally got the solution.

select * from question where questionid >" + id + " order by questionid limit 1

Answer (score 0):

Try using the API for displaying the list from database http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: That page doesnt help in how to use buttons with cursoradap.pavandroid

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to show all question in  a listview then why you are using  a listview,You can store all the questions in an  array and pass it to a viewpager

```
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),arrOfquestions);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Ya but if we have many question db is better right? we can also insert ques if needed also...so i thought db is better.

Comment: yeah db will be there only ,you  pass your content from db into an array to display it in viewapger,pager and listView are just approach for showing your data,or binding your data to a view,not storing.

Comment: Now i understand what u say but i dont know how to use viewpager.any links to learn about it?srishti Roy